# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать сохранение по выходу из приложения? Делаю на Unity, код на c#

Tags: c#, unity3d

С сохранением у меня все ок, но оно работает по нажатию определенной кнопки, как мне сделать так, чтобы когда человек выходил из приложения ему выскакивал баннер типа "Сохранить перед выходом? Да/Нет". Я сделал сохранение через PlayerPrefs уже подумываю просто запихать его в метод Update(), хоть это и не разумно, но все же хочется найти менее требовательный, в плане ресурсов, способ.

Comment: а выход из приложения происходит по кнопке ? Или это мобильное приложение которое человек может  свернуть и выбросить из памяти ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для автоматизации сохранения можно использовать методы `OnApplicationPause` и `OnApplicationQuit`

```
private void OnApplicationPause(bool _pause)
{        
    if (!_pause)
    {
        //Игра снимается с паузы (разворячивается, восстанавлдивается)          
    }
    else
    {    
        //Игра ставится на паузе (н-р, сворачивается)
        //Сохранение
        //...
    }
}

private void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    //Приложение завершает работу
    //Сохранение
    //...
}
```

Эти методы достаточно реализовать (строго с соблюдением регистра!) в одном из скриптов-наследнике `MonoBehaviour` (на-р SaveManager) и добиться того, что бы этот скрипт всегда был у Вас на сцене.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую!

Comment: все получилось))

Comment: @dreamboy, значит, оцените ответ и пометьте как "Правильный". И так же проверьте Ваш предыдущий вопрос - там тоже ответ дожидается оценки и смены статуса. После этого вопросы будут считаться закрытыми.